# NodeJS : Need Help To build object with some Brackets and Braces

Tags: javascript, encoding, nodes, stringify, url-parsing

In my project I use request lib () and i would like to use [qsStringifyOptions](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) for query parametre but it's to much complicated in my case :/

In their documentation they link [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) module to use qsStringifyOptions like them

I would like to have this URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:80/endpoint?foo=bar[baz:3]&aaa=[{baa:X,caa:XX,daa:[{eaa:Z,faa:ZZ}]}]&data[B]=BB&data[C]=CC
```

but I have this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:80/endpoint?foo=bar[baz:3]&aaa=[%7B%22baa%22:%22X%22,%22caa%22:%22XX%22,%22daa%22:[%7B%22eaa%22:%22Z%22,%22faa%22:%22ZZ%22%7D]%7D]&data[B]=BB&data[C]=CC
```

With this solution, the 'foo' attribute and data[B] and data[C] work fine but 'aaa' attribut not at all :

```
{ // some standar param URI, methode ...
    useQuerystring: false,
    qsStringifyOptions : {encodeValuesOnly: true, encode: false,  indices: false},
    qs : {
      foo: 'bar[baz:1]',
      aaa:'[{"baa":"X","caa":"XX","daa":[{"eaa":"Z","faa":"ZZ"}]}]',
      data: {B:'BB', C:'CC'}
    }
}
```

what i'm doing wrong?  i just want it not to parse the 'aaa' attribute
thank you in advance for your help and your time

Comment: Would it not be possible to send your qs object directly, instead of stringifying it in the URL? Encoding special characters in a URL is unavoidable, I guess. You'll have to de-encode them afterwards.

Comment: I don't know why but if i put in hard all parameters in URL param of request, all brackets and braces are encoder %5B %5D ...

Comment: Yes I know, as I said this is pretty much unavoidable. Not all characters are allowed in URLs. Forbidden characters are encoded, so they must then be decoded. What about my first question?

Comment: OK we didn't understand each other, that's the first thing I did, put the json object directly in qs param